# console created scheduled task does not exist?

Tags: cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks

Creating scheduled task form command line with elevated privileges in windows 10:

```
schtasks.exe /Create /XML "FILES\test.xml" /TN "TEST" /RU "SYSTEM" /RP
```

it report

```
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "TEST" has successfully been created.
```

but when perform

```
schtasks.exe /query /TN "TEST"
```

got

```
ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Task is not visible in scheduled tasks manager GUI, and even task could be infinitelly recreated (following multiple usage of first command without error) which IMHO should not be possible because the name is same.

What am I doing wrong?